# Obtengo failed to lazily initialize a collection of role, cuando hago una peticion GET

Tags: spring, jpa

Estoy tratando de obtener todos los usuarios, la clase User tiene una lista como atributo creo que ese es el error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Friendship",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idFriend"))
    private Set<User> friends = new HashSet<>();
```

y cuando quiero obtener todos los usuarios me sale este error

```
 {
      "timestamp": 1556678614095,
      "status": 500,
      "error": "Internal Server Error",
      "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
      "message": "Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection
 of role: com.example.demo.model.User.friends, could not initialize proxy - no 
Session; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize
 a collection of role: com.example.demo.model.User.friends, could not initialize 
proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-
>com.example.demo.model.User[\"friends\"])",
      "path": "/user/getUsers"
    }
```

este es el procedimiento que estoy usando  para obtener todos los usuarios:

En el controller:

```
@GetMapping("/getUsers")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
        log.info("getUser");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userServiceImpl.getUsers(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

y en el servicio :

```
 public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En `@OneToMany` el fetch type default es `Lazy`, esto hace que el atributo `friends` no sea instanciado hasta que se haga `getFriends()`.

En tu caso `getFriends()` se está llamando cuando se está serializando el objeto a Json para retornar el objeto. El problema es que en ese momento ya no cuentas con la `Session` de `JPA`, es decir, que la llamada a `getFriends()` debería haber ocurrido antes cuando estabas buscando los datos en el `userRepository`.

Podes cambiar el comportamiento default con `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`.
Esto hace que friends se instancie junto con el resto de los atributos.

Comment: tu respuesta soluciono pero creo que genero otro tipo de error, hice otra pregunta   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/260292/valores-vacios-en-peticion-post