# Obtengo este error en peticion post: tabla no encontrada

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Estoy queriendo relacionar amigos de usuarios, el problema que tengo es como obtener los amigos de un usuario?
Creo que parte de mi problema es que estoy poniendo como atributo la lista de amigos en la clase Usuario,  `private Set<User> friends = new HashSet<>();`  eso esta bien?

Estoy poniendo este json por medio de `swagger`, ya que son usuarios existentes en la bd.

```
{
  "friend": {
    "email": "string",
    "friends": [],
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "password": "string"
  },
  "owner": {
    "email": "wwww",
    "friends": [],
    "id": 3,
    "name": "dsadsa",
    "password": "d"
  }
}
```

Este es mi controller, donde todo inicia:

```
@PostMapping("/addFriend")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@RequestBody Friendship friendship) {
        log.info("addFriend");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(userServiceImpl.createLinkWithFriends(friendship), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Este es el servicio:

```
public User createLinkWithFriends(Friendship friendship) {
    User owner=userRepository.findById(friendship.getOwner().getId());
    User friend=userRepository.findById(friendship.getFriend().getId());
    owner.addFriend(friend);

    friendsRepository.save(friendship);
    return owner;
}
```

y este es el repositorio User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Friendship",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idFriend"))
    private Set<User> friends = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name, long id, String password, String email) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void addFriend(User userFriend){
        this.friends.add(userFriend);
    }
```

Este es la clase Friendship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Friendship")
public class Friendship implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long idFriend;

    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;

    @ManyToOne
    private User friend;

    public Friendship() {

    }

    public User getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(User owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public User getFriend() {
        return friend;
    }

    public void setFriend(User friend) {
        this.friend = friend;
    }
}
```

obtengo este error cuando hago mvn clean package

```
2019-05-03 23:54:59.925  INFO 20200 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2019-05-03 23:54:59.925  INFO 20200 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-05-03 23:54:59.931  INFO 20200 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2019-05-03 23:54:59.979  INFO 20200 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-05-03 23:55:00.132  INFO 20200 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2019-05-03 23:55:01.094  INFO 20200 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2019-05-03 23:55:01.132  INFO 20200 --- [           main] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: friendship
2019-05-03 23:55:01.133  INFO 20200 --- [           main] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: friendship
2019-05-03 23:55:01.136  WARN 20200 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.sp
ringframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/Hibern
ateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFac
tory
2019-05-03 23:55:01.152  INFO 20200 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-05-03 23:55:01.184 ERROR 20200 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/
HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate Sess
ionFactory
```

Lo subi mi proyecto a github  https://github.com/hubmanS/traslateInClick, agradeceria mucho si hacen la prueba

Comment: Me parece que tenes algo raro aca: `createLinkWithFriends`. Esto esta bien? `user.addFriend(user);`

Comment: @Juan el metodo addFriend añade un nuevo usuario a la lista de amigos, asi:   public void addFriend(User userFriend){
        this.friends.add(userFriend);
    }

Comment: Pero estas pasando como amigo al mismo usuario sobre el que llamaste el metodo.

Comment: Dónde se genera el error? En el stack strace no lo llego a ver.

Comment: @Juan no entiendo mucho el error pero obtengo esto en swagger               {
  "timestamp": 1556829987444,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
  "message": "detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.model.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.model.User",
  "path": "/user/addFriend"
}

Comment: @Juan ya actualice mi pregunta, encontre el error pero no se como solucionarlo

Comment: El error lo que dice es que tenés un entity de User que está fuera del contexto de persistencia (como desconectado) y en ese estado, detached, no se puede persistir, primero hay que volver a conectarlo al contexto de persistencia. El stack trace en algún lugar debería tener una referencia a que programa (tuyo) y que línea producen ese problema. (Lo que agregaste del stack strace es solo la consecuencia)

Comment: @Juan puse otras lineas del error, y si tienes razon, se produce en la funcion  createLinkWithFriends

Comment: `Running hbm2ddl schema update` Esta es la actualización automática de la estructura de la base de datos en base a las modificaciones de las clases (Entities). `Table not found: friendship` No se encuentra una tabla con nombre 'friendship'. En el entity el nombre de la tabla es lo que va entre comillas en el annotation @Table atributo name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Respecto del error: `detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.model.User`

Y en base a: `at com.example.demo.service.UserServiceImpl.createLinkWithFriends(UserServiceImpl.java:42)`

Me parece que el problema es que estás salvando `friendship` tal cual como vino por parámetro, y por lo que se vé los objetos que lo conforman no son del contexto de persistencia sino lo que se ha deserializado en el controller que envió el usuario.

Me parece que el error se puede corregir al reemplazar los objetos del frienship por los entities correspondientes levantados de los repositorios o mejor creando una instancia nueva para asegurar que el friendship no tenga un id preseteado.

Finalmente obtengo una nueva instancia del `User` entity `owner` desde el repositorio para devolver el resultado al final del método. De esta forma me aseguro que la colección esté conformada con los entities persistidos. (Puede que esto último no haga falta)

```
public User createLinkWithFriends(Friendship friendship) {
    User owner=userRepository.findById(friendship.getOwner().getId());
    User friend=userRepository.findById(friendship.getFriend().getId());
    Frienship newFriendship = new FriendShip();
    newFriendship.setOwner(owner);
    newFriendship.setFriend(friend);

    newFriendship = friendsRepository.save(newFriendship);

    owner = userRepository.findById(owner.getId());
    return owner;
}
```

**EDICIÓN I:**

Armé un sistema imitando las clases que tenés armadas y lo modifiqué para que funcione. Probablementa hay otras decisiones que pude haber tomado que harían que la solución fuera diferente, es decir, esta es una solución pero no la única:

Aparte del cambio explicado en la primera respuesta cambié los mapeos y ese cambio repercutió en otras modificaciones.

[image: El modelo de base de datos que use como tener una referencia]

## Clase Usuario

1. El cambio mas importante es que el OneToMany va hacia Friendship y no hacia Usuario.
2. El set `friends` de `Friendship` mapea al atributo `owner` de la clase `Friendship`. Todos los `Friendship` con el mismo `owner` son las amistaes del `User`.

   Pude dejar como `LAZY` el fetch en lugar de `EAGER` que evita levantar amigos de amigos de amigos ....

   `@JsonBackReference` es para evitar los ciclos en la serialización a Json (A amigo de B amigo de C amigo de A amigo de B amigo de C ....).

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="owner")
@JsonBackReference 
private Set<Friendship> friends = new HashSet<>();
```

Como nota personal, evaluaría quitar la colección de `friends` junto con el mapeo, para manejarme directamente con el entity `Friendship`.

## Clase Friendship

1. En los OneToMany agregué los join column para identificar la columna correcta de la tabla que es la foreigh key a la tabla User
2. El `MapsId` que estaba originalmente, se usaría en caso de una `EmbeddedId`, que sería otra forma de armar la solución

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="owner") // Campo de la tabla friendship que es fk de User
@JsonManagedReference
private User owner;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="friend") // Campo de la tabla friendship que es fk de User
private User friend;
```

## Controller

En el cotroller, como la serialización del Json limitó el agregado de la colección friends, agregué un endpoint más para recuperar los amigos de un usuario.
Los métodos están modificados para recibir parametros de un formulario en lugar de objetos json, pero esto no cambia la escencia.

```
@PostMapping("/addFriend")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@RequestParam("owner") Long ownerId, @RequestParam("friend") Long friendId) {
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(userService.createLinkWithFriends(ownerId, friendId), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/owner/{id}/friends")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getFriendsOf(@PathVariable("id") Long ownerId) {
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(userService.getFriendsOf(ownerId), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

## Servicios

Lo mismo que está como primera respuesta mas un método para buscar a los amigos.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public User createLinkWithFriends(Long ownerId, Long friendId) {
    User owner = userRepository.findById(ownerId).orElse(null);
    User friend = userRepository.findById(friendId).orElse(null);

    if(owner == null) throw new RuntimeException("Owner not found");
    if(friend == null) throw new RuntimeException("Friend not found");

    Friendship newFriendship = new Friendship();
    newFriendship.setOwner(owner);
    newFriendship.setFriend(friend);

    newFriendship = friendshipRepository.save(newFriendship);   
    owner = userRepository.findById(owner.getId()).orElse(null);    
    return owner;
}

@Override
public List<User> getFriendsOf(Long ownerId) {
    List<User> rtn = new ArrayList<>();
    User user = userRepository.findById(ownerId).orElse(null);
    if(user!=null) {
        for(Friendship fsh : user.getFriends()) {
            rtn.add(fsh.getFriend());
        }
        return rtn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: en el error dice  where user0_.id=? por que signo de interrogacion, no sera ese el error?

Comment: modifique con tu metodo pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error

Comment: Cambiaste todo el método y te da exactamente el mismo error?

Comment: La verdad ya no se que más decirte, para mí el problema estaba con los objetos owner y friend del Friendship que estabas creando.  Si bien como está mapeada la tabla de Friendship me genera alguas dudas, para decirte más tengo que tratar de reproducir el problema. Si querés, probá sacando el annotation de @MapsId en Friendship, salvo que tengas claro para que lo estás usando.

Comment: Fijate la Edición I, hice un demo usando tus clases y ahi te cuento lo que modifiqué para que funcione. Por ahí no es lo que esperabas porque no es la única forma de hacerlo.

Comment: sobre esto:   Como nota personal, evaluaría quitar la colección de friends junto con el mapeo, para manejarme directamente con el entity Friendship,       como lo quito?  por que al momento de crear un nuevo usuario obtengo esto Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.demo
.model.User]]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type (com.exampl
e.demo.model.Friendship)

Comment: Los obtenes usando el friendshipDao buscando por Owner (el id del owner).

Comment: obtengo el error cuando estoy creando un nuevo usuario